# How to Secure the Excel AddIn

Tags: excel, security, vsto, add-in

I have got a question to Excel Community here :

I have prepared an AddIn and it is ready to install for all the users on the machine. I fear that a malicious user can disable the addin through Excel Office Button =>AddIn.

what I need is that no one should be able to disable my addin? 
My Questions are :

1.Is it possible?
   2. If so, how can this be achieved? 
   3. Would signing code digitally or creating a root certificate for the addin before deploying, helps Excel to load it successfully and stopping a malicious user from disable the addin ?

any type of inputs are highly appreciated??

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this, for a number of very good reasons.

Comment: like what? what are those good reasons? to what extent I can do this?

Comment: #1: I no longer need your addin and want to uninstall it.  #2: your addin conflicts with another addin and I need to uninstall yours to get the other one working.  That's plenty of reasons for me :-)

Comment: I'm afraid you won't able to do that - the keyword here is 'Security'.

Comment: How do you define "malicious user"? If I want to uninstall a piece of software, or disable an add-in, that's not malicious.

Comment: I consider any piece of software (add-in or otherwise) malicious if it doesn't allow me to uninstall it. What you should be asking is how to encourage users to keep it installed. Does it tie in with any other Excel based programs? What happens when a user uninstalls it? Loss of functionality? Can't run custom formulas built-in to a workbook?

Comment: @guitarthrower I would reframe my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enabled/disabled behavior of an add-in is controlled by a registry key. Excel deactivates your addin by updating the "LoadBehavior" value in this key:

Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\[youraddin] .

Although it might be not a good idea (you need to consider carefully), you could "secure" the add-in by setting permissions on it's registry key (allow write access to this key only for a specific user, or disable write access for everybody).

You can modify permissions for a registry key by hand (i.e. by registry editor), by installer, or by group policies.

Note that normally if a user disables some add-in, it is disabled for that user only, and not for all users (value in user's HKCU key is updated) - assuming that user is not admin or UAC is activated. To disable an add-in for all users, the "malicious" user must have admin rights and must start office application as admin.

If don't want allow users to disable the add-in even for themselves only, you might need to do some extra job of securing their user's registry.